# string object has no attribute 'append' in python

Tags: python, list, matrix, terminal, runtime-error

It seems that this code wont run due to an 'str' object has no attribute 'append'  error and according to the terminal the problems is due to the following line:
new_arr[rows*i + j].append(arr[i][j])

I am trying to convert a matrix to a list.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
def two_d_translate(arr):

    rows = len(arr)
    cols = len(arr[0])
    total_elements = rows * cols
    new_arr = ['0']*total_elements
    #the number of rows in a mat 
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        for j in range(len(arr[0])):
            new_arr[rows*i + j].append(arr[i][j])
      
    return new_arr
```

Comment: `new_arr` is a 1-dimensional array of strings, not a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: `new_arr[rows*i + j]` is the string `'0'`. What are you expecting `append()` to do?

Comment: you're `append`ing onto a string based on the error, so I would assume you're trying to `append` to a `'0'` that is in the list. in fact, `new_arr` is still a 1D array, so when you access it with one subscript, you're accessing a `'0'` directly instead of, say, a row of `'0'`s.

Answer (score 2):

`new_arr[rows*i + j]` is a string, not a list, you can't append to it.

You don't need to append anything, you just need to replace that element of the list.

```
new_arr[rows*i + j] = arr[i][j]
```

But actually there's no need to pre-fill the list and then assign it. You can just append to the list in the loop.

```
def two_d_translate(arr):
    new_arr = []
    for row in arr:
        for col in row:
            new_arr.append(col)
    return new_arr
```

Answer (score 0):

new_arr is allocated with string values instead of 2d array

```
new_arr = [[] for i in range(total_elements)]
```